# the same old "the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect"

Tags: c#, linq

I know there are many questions about this. I have read them and I have made the same name and type for the anonymous types properties. Still I get the error in the title.

Code is:

```
var v = (from o in dataContext.pp_orders.Where(p => p.ID > lastOrderID).OrderBy(p => p.DueDate)
                 join part in dataContext.pp_parts on o.ProductID equals part.ProductID
                 join op in dataContext.pp_operations on new { ID2 = part.ID } equals new { ID2 = (int)op.PartID }
                 select (x => new JobModel { o = o, op = op }));
```

The error is at the second join.

**[UPDATE]**

It seems the join equals are correct. This query works (no error):

```
var v = (from o in dataContext.pp_orders.Where(p => p.ID > lastOrderID).OrderBy(p => p.DueDate)
                 join part in dataContext.pp_parts on o.ProductID equals part.ProductID
                 join op in dataContext.pp_operations on part.ID equals (int)op.PartID
                 select op);
```

The problem is with the select clause. I don't understand why it gives the error in the title at that select clause.

```
select (x => new JobModel { o = o, op = op })
```

Comment: Can't you just use `join op in dataContext.pp_operations on part.ID equals (int)op.PartID`?

Comment: If I use that I get the same error which I understand because the members ID and PartID don't have the same name. But I do not understand why I get the error with explicit member assignment new { ID2 = ... }

Comment: You are 100% certain that `part.ID` is an `int` and not nullable?  BTW the properties in the join clause don't have to have the same name, so `part.ID equals (int)op.PartID` should work.  The fact that you're projecting them to an anonymous type means that the _type_ has to have the same property names, which they do.  It's the _type_ that's the issue, not the property names.

Comment: the equals clauses are correct. please see my update in the question text

Comment: Your update is a different query - you are now casting both `productID`s to `int`s in the first join. Are you sure that isn't where the original error was coming from.?

Comment: What are you supposed to be projecting to? `(x => new JobModel { o = o, op = op })` has no meaningful type... there's nothing the compiler can infer for you.

Comment: I'm also dubious of putting the lambda into the final select - you should just be able to write `select new JobModel { o = o, op = op }`

Comment: Rhumborl, you are correct. I simply wrote select new JobModel { o = o, op = op } and it works. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Rhumborl if you want please write an answer and I will select it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing query syntax and method syntax.  Method syntax uses lamdbas to project data, while query syntax uses more natural sql-like syntax:

change your select to:

```
select new JobModel { o = o, op = op }
```